# VBA Excel - Application.Interactive = True and Userforms causing the application window to go into the background

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with my Excel window disappearing into the background (or rather, the topmost Z -1 window position) when I run some macros containing a UserForm. This issue seems to be related somehow to the `Application.Interactive` property being set to `True` at the start of these macros, i.e. the problem goes away when I comment out that command.

As I can't really remove the `Application.Interactive = True` command from my subroutines, I've had to put in an `BringWindowToTop` API call in at the end of every macro to get the window to return to the the top. The problem with this is not just that the screen will flash when the macro finishes running, which is not necessarily a huge issue, but rather that this feels like an inelegant solution because I don't understand what's causing the problem in the first place.

Again, this only occurs when I have a Userform which are called as part of the subroutine but I can't see any problems with how that is written. This issue also occurs with both Excel 2010 and 2013.

Please find below a snippets of code for a Module and UserForm which are similar to how my macros function and which replicate the issue. I've left the API calls in for completeness, but they are commented out.

Does anyone have an idea about what is going on here and how it can be fixed?

Module Code

```
'Public Declarations
'APIs
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Sub Window_To_Background_Test()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Interactive = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'ThisWorkbooksHandle = GetActiveWindow

    With UserForm1
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
        .Show
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Interactive = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    'Call BringWindowToTop(ThisWorkbooksHandle)

End Sub
```

UserForm Code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set Label1 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test", True)
    With Label1
        .Caption = "Test"
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 50
        .Top = 10
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Interactive` is only used when you are using another application to call Excel to perform some task (usually through OLE or ADO, etc.) so sending the window to the background is normal behavior.  For an Excel macro this command is unnecessary.

Comment: The macros do query another database using an `ADODB.Connection` command. The queries can take quite awhile and the macros then breakdown the returned Recordset into a series of tables. So, best not to have users randomly clicking. Also, another reason for setting `Application.Interactive = False` is that there are some macros which generate reports and this allows commands like `Sheet1.PageSetup.FitToPageswide = 1` to be invoked without an individual users printer settings causing odd page sizing. If this is expected behaviour, why does this only occur when a userform is called?

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote.  You are calling it from within excel. `Application.Interactive` does not need to be changed in this case.  Users won't be able to randomly click while your macro is running anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro I disagree that .Interactive is only used when controlling Excel from another application. The MS doc says it's "useful" for DDE, but doesn't say that it's only purpose. There are many possible reasons one might want to block user-clicks and keystrokes while macros are running. Note, the MS doc example is Excel controlling an external app, not the other way around as you said. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.interactive